# How to make Telegram BOT reply to a specific message?

Tags: javascript, rest, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I would like to make my BOT reply to a specific message like this:

[image]

I am using the "reply_to_msg_id" with the ID of the message to replies to, but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance,

Giacomo

Comment: What does it say when you send the request with reply_to_msg_id? It should return an error if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't.

Comment: Then use another API for your bot development, it should always return a response for you to find out about the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reply_to_message_id` and **NOT** `reply_to_msg_id`.

Source: [Telegram sendMessage API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const { message_id: originalMessageId, from: { username }, chat: { id: chatId } } = msg;

  bot.sendMessage(chatId, `welcome ${username}`, {
    reply_to_message_id: originalMessageId
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg, match)=> {
var text = "hi user welcome to bot"
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,text,{reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id})
```

})

use replay_to_message_id

Comment: OP has already mentioned that he's using `reply_to_message_id` and that it's not working. Please elaborate on why do you your solution would work.